# reCaptcha in android xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin.android, recaptcha

I would like to implement captcha in Xamarin android app. I got hold of this [integrate googles reCaptcha validation in Android](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-integrate-googles-recaptcha-validation-in-android/). But its a native android project. I also found [this](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/blob/master/safetynet/samples/SafetyNetSample/MainActivity.cs), but I am unable to make it work. I am getting `Failed to Check Compatibility` alert. The API `SafetyNetClass.SafetyNetApi.AttestAsync` is returning an error. Not sure why.

Is there any other way to go about captcha validation. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the `SafetyNetApi` to do `reCaptcha` validation you need to:

- Set your `minSdkVersion` to 14 or higher
- Make sure you include `Google Repository` in your SDK tools
- Install `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.SafetyNet` package
- Sign your app package name in [reCAPTCHA Android signup site](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#androidsignup) and get your Site key and Secret key

After this you launch the verification of the captcha:

```
try
{
    var response = await SafetyNetClass.GetClient(this.context).VerifyWithRecaptchaAsync("YOUR_API_SITE_KEY");
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.TokenResult))
    {
        // Validate the user response token using the
        // reCAPTCHA siteverify API.
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // Handle exception
    throw ex;
}
```

After you get the token result not null, you need to verify it using the [reCAPTCHA siteverify API](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify). Here is where you need to use the `Secret key`.

Pay attention to error handling when communicating with the reCaptcha service. You can check more about this following the links below.

More Info:

- https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/recaptcha#validate-response
- https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify
- http://android-er.blogspot.com/2017/06/example-using-safetynet-recaptcha-api.html (careful here because some of the methods used here are obsolete)