# How to protect your WebAPI against bots for both mobile and web?

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, recaptcha

I have a requirement to protect my backend from bots. My backend is an `ASP.NET Core WebAPI`. Besides, I have a `Xamarin.Forms` cross-platform mobile client and `Angular` client. I know that it's nonsense to show a [reCaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha) on a mobile phone (at least not very common). On the other hand, the `Angular` client must have a reCaptcha validation on my sign up page. So what's the best practise to protect my backend from bots.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to protect not frontside, but backend.
The bot can use API calls for using your service. So, if your API is on GET requests mostly or on HTTP (not HTTPS), it will be very easy. So solution on angular does not give you full protection from bots. 
For bot protection from backend side, you can check resources like this https://www.cloudflare.com/
Also, you can check this website for more services: https://riskemy.com/best-website-bot-protection/

If you want to use only front protection, on angular is ReCaptcha: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-recaptcha

For Xamarin (Android only):
[reCaptcha in android xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52165506/recaptcha-in-android-xamarin)

Comment: I haven't met a reCaptcha library that can be used in `Xamarin.Forms` for both iOS & Android. Do you know any @gerald-versluis? Or have you seen a mobile app that makes reCaptcha? Does it make sense?